# How do I sort an ASP.NET DataGrid by the length of a field?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid where each column has a SortExpression. I would like the sort expression to be the equivalent of "ORDER BY LEN(myField)".

I have tried

```
SortExpression="LEN(myField)"
```

but this throws an exception as it is not valid syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about returning the len by the query already, but don't show that column, only use it as your original column's sortexpression?

I don't think that your idea is supported by default.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your SQL flavor the following could work:

```
SELECT
 ColumnA as FieldA
 , ColumnB as FieldB
 , LEN(ColumnA) as FieldL
FROM TableName
ORDER BY L
```

And then do

```
SortExpression="FieldL"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SortExpression` parameter specifies the name of the column to sort, followed by "ASC" or "DESC" to control the order.

You could change the `DataType` property of the column to specifiy a user defined type whose comparer function compares string lengths. It won't be a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, you could write your query like:

```
query.OrderBy(column => column.MyField.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Had some time to test. I was able to get **SortExpression="Description.Length"** to work. Is this 1.1, 2.0 or 3.5?

Comment: Hi Jason. It's Visual Studio 2008, running on .NET 2.0. I've tested it again and can't get it to work as you describe. The data is returned from a stored procedure, using a DataAdapter. Thanks, RB.